How can I have the user switcher default to being onscreen the Ubuntu 22.04LTS lock screen?
I've just installed the default install of Ubuntu 22.04LTS Desktop edition after a hiatus of using Ubuntu for a few years.
It is installed on an office computer and there are 2 very regular users that use this computer each day. After a few minutes of no use on either of the 2 users logged in session the screen locks. This is good but the lock screen that appears always defaults to the user that was in the current session and asks for their password.
What I am wanting is that when the screen locks and eventually goes blank (again all good) ... but when a user moves the mouse (the most common way to unlock the screen) or clicks enter then it brings up the user switcher so they can choose which user they are and click on that name entering their password.
If the user is already logged in it will return to their session ... if not then it will start a session for them.
By doing this it will save time when the 2 regular users want to use the office computer and allows them to restore their last used session.
FYI I know about:

the user switch icon at the bottom of the lock screen but this creates a second step and a small delay while the user switcher loads
pushing CTRL+ALT+F1 to get to the login screen and CTRL+ALT+F2 for the first logged in user ... and CTRL+ALT+F3 for the second logged in user ... and so on but again this isn't a graphical solution.

Thanks in advance.
Update 27th April '24:
I've also found the following link which indicates this was potentially possible in other display managers (not sure which greeter Ubuntu 22.04LTS uses as default):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/878836


I don't understand.... what is it that you are trying to get around?
